# Disabled button is clickable on Edge browser

Tags: html, angularjs, button, microsoft-edge, disabled-control

I have problem with Edge browser. In my web site I have buttons with span tags inside them. In this span tags I bind text and icons. So far I had no problem but on Edge browser it is possible to click on disabled buttons. After investigating problem I found out that, when button contains span tags inside, it is possible to click on button. Here is how it looks on my web site:

```
<button id="btnRefresh" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="refresh()" ng-disabled="performingAction">
    <span ng-class="performingAction && action == 'refresh' ? 'fa fa-cog fa-spin' :'fa fa-refresh'"></span>
    <span>{{ refresh }}</span>
</button>
```

Here is example to testing:

```html
<button type="button" disabled="disabled" onclick='alert("test");'>
    <span>Click me!</span>
</button>
```

One option would be to hide buttons instead of disabling, but I prefer to disable them. Please suggest solution to over come this issue.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I've logged it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1748050

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in Microsoft Edge

Comment: @Popnoodles: That does not make the question off-topic. It's on-topic, the answer being "It's a bug". See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268242/how-to-mark-a-fixed-problem for a meta discussion.

Comment: @sleske yes but you don't get enough options. The closest may be "Offtopic because... Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

Answer (score 5):

Just set

> pointer-events: none;

for disabled buttons.

Here's CSS to disable all disabled elements everywhere:

```
*[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

[`pointer-events` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Excellent! Why do it in Javascript if it can be done in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Microsoft Edge. Disabled buttons accept clicks if they contain any HTML elements (i.e. if they contain anything else than just text).

Reported multiple times via Microsoft Connect:

- [Event bubbles from child element into  element](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1748050) (by SO user Ryan Joy)
- [Bootstrap/Jquery disabled buttons generate click events and show tooltips even disabled](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1631564/)

The bug was still present in Build 10565 (16 October 2015).
**It was fixed in the November update, Build 10586.**

---

A possible (but ugly) workaround is to call some Javascript in `onclick` for every button, which then checks if the button is disabled and returns `false` (thus suppressing the click event).

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is now fixed as of Build 25.10586.0.0.

Comment: @RyanJoy: Yes - the bug you opened in Microsoft Connect (linked above) has also been closed.

Answer (score 1):

One work around I've come up with using angularjs is inspired by Ben Nadel's blog [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2926-overriding-directive-definitions-in-angularjs.htm)

So for example:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive(
    "span",
    function spanDirective() {
        return ({
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.disabled || e.target.parentNode.disabled) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                })
            },
            restrict: "E",
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Forgot to add browser detection in the example, but I guess you'd need to do that. Also this will override click for all span tags, so you might want to define your own instead of overriding such a primitive one

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not always going to be using a span element and probably don't want to create a new directive for every element type, a more general workaround would be to decorate the ngClick directive to prevent the event from reaching the real ngClick's internal event handler when the event is fired on a disabled element.

```
var yourAppModule = angular.module('myApp');
// ...
yourAppModule.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('ngClickDirective', ['$delegate', '$window', function($delegate, $window) {
        var isEdge = /windows.+edge\//i.test($window.navigator.userAgent);

        if (isEdge) {
            var directiveConfig = $delegate[0];
            var originalCompileFn = directiveConfig.compile;

            directiveConfig.compile = function() {
                var origLinkFn = originalCompileFn.apply(directiveConfig, arguments);

                // Register a click event handler that will execute before the one the original link
                // function registers so we can stop the event.
                return function linkFn(scope, element) {
                    element.on('click', function(event) {
                        if (event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.disabled) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    });

                    return origLinkFn.apply(null, arguments);
                };
            };
        }

        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```