# Link Disable property not working in Microsoft EDGE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I dynamically disabled a link with `<a>` tag using `Javascript` and `CSS`.

CSS class:

```
 .notactive
         {
            pointer-events: none;
            cursor: default;
         }
```

JS :

```
 td.children[0].className = 'notactive';
 td.children[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Rendered HTML  :

```
<td width="180" runat="server" id="LinkId">

<a href="../mypage.aspx?querystring" id="lnk" class="notactive" disabled="disabled" target="iframe1" onclick="alternate('check');"> Personal Page </a>

</td>
```

It is working for IE 11, FireFox, Safari and Chrome but in `EDGE` browser it is not working. What is missing here ?

The requirement is to disable the link for EDGE Browser. I used `disabled` property as I thought it will work for all browsers but the problem still exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33371677/4913153

Comment: is there any other way to handle this without using Angular JS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
td.children[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

document.getElementsByClassName("notactive")[0].disabled=false;
//you can set true or false with the conditions.
```